# Checking error output is on my errorlist

Tags: java, variables, enums

I have the following code for logging all the errors after every command I run in cmd with my tool. (It runs `p4 integrate` commands, about 1000-1500/task)

```
if (errorArrayList.size() > 0) {
            LoggerSingleton.I.writeDebugInfoTimeStampedLog("[INFO-CMD] CommandExecuter.java -> runAndGetResults: errors happened while running the following command: [ " + commandResultBean.getCommand() + " ]");

            for (int i = 0; i < errorArrayList.size(); i++) {
                LoggerSingleton.I.writeDebugErrorTimeStampedLog(errorArrayList.get(i));
                commandResultBean.addToCLI_Error(errorArrayList.get(i));
            }

            LoggerSingleton.I.writeDebugInfoTimeStampedLog("[INFO-CMD] CommandExecuter.java -> runAndGetResults: Listing errors of command [" + commandResultBean.getCommand() + "] finished");
        }
```

The feature that I'm working on right now is check the error I get, and if that's on a predefined error list (list of errors that doesn't matter, and in fact not real errors, for example *"all revision(s) already integrated"*) do nothing else, but when it's a "real" error, write it to an other log file too (Because these debug logs way too long for the users of the tool, it's made for the developers more likely).

The question is, what is the best way for this?

- I want to avoid big deceleration. I have many commands, but the number of errors less then the commands, but that is not unusual at all that I get 700-800 "irrelevant" errors in one task.
- I will use another class to make the I/O part, and that is not a problem to extend the running time in case we catch a "real" error.
- The list is constant, it is okay if it can be modified only by coding.

At the moment I don't know what type to use (2-3 single `String`s, `List`, `Array` ...). What type should I use? I never used `enum`s in Java before, in this one should I?

I guess a `for` or `foreach` and `errorArrayList.get(i).contains(<myVariable>)`in a method is the only option for the checking. 
If I'm wrong, there is a better way to do this?

**EDIT**

If I have an `ArrayList<String>`called `knownErrors` with the irrelevant errors (can define only parts of it), and I use the following code will better performance than a method wrote above? Also, can I use it if I have only parts of the String? How?

```
if (errorArrayList.removeAll(knownErrors) {
    //do the logging and stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList itself has a method removeAll(Collection c) which removes all the elements which are matching with input collection elements. Below program show it evidently. So if you have the known error to be skipped in arraylist and pass it to removeall method it will remove the known errors and errorArrayList will have only new errors.
[image]

Comment: This answer is helpful, but I'm not sure if this is the most effective way at all. But thank you, I will update my question with this.